# Swap Words in File with hash

Tags: ruby

I have a text file and I am trying to replace certain lines with the values in a hash.  I am trying to make it loop through the file, and swap out anything that matches the hash.  For some reason this isn't working, it only duplicates the file, doesn't swap anything out.  Any Ideas?

```
HASHBROWNS{

'mustard'  =>  'dijon',
'ketchup'  =>  'catsup',

}


File.open('new_hashed_file.txt', 'w') do |file|
  File.open('oldfile.txt', 'r').readlines.each do |swaparoo|
       if HASHBROWNS.has_key?(swaparoo.downcase)
             file.puts HASHBROWNS[swaparoo.downcase]
       else
             file.puts swaparoo
       end
  end
end
```

Thanks

Ryn

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this line:

```
File.open('oldfile.txt', 'r').readlines.each do |swaparoo|
```

to this:

```
File.open('oldfile.txt', 'r').readlines.map(&:chomp).each do |swaparoo|
```

The problem is your array of lines contains newlines.

Comment: The newline thing threw me for a loop!  Thanks Worked great!

Answer (score 2):

When you read data with `readlines` there will be a newline present in each string. This is what's making your match miss. The easy way is to just trim it off with `chomp`. You may want do modify your test slightly:

```
File.open('new_hashed_file.txt', 'w') do |file|
  File.open('oldfile.txt', 'r').readlines.each do |line|
    line = line.chomp.downcase

    file.puts HASHBROWNS[line] || line
  end
end
```

One thing to pay attention to is not repeatedly calling methods like `downcase` if you can simply save the result to a temporary variable and recycle it.

Comment: I also am implementing your way of downcasing, much more efficient!  Thanks!